# Yosemite: NSSavePanel: __NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to Yosemite, I'm getting a very weird crash when I run a NSSavePanel in my app. For example, I select openDocument: and it crashes. Or I open the panel to browse files and it crashes.

```
An uncaught exception was raised
2014-10-24 09:51:28.429 MyApp[2240:374020] *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
2014-10-24 09:51:28.431 MyApp[2240:374020] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x97c59343 __raiseError + 195
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x973bea2a objc_exception_throw + 276
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x97b1cf8c -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 204
    3   MyApp                               0x0013c830 -[NSArray(CocoaDevUsersAdditions) firstObject] + 41
    4   AppKit                              0x94567f16 _NSAccessibilityEntryPointValueForAttribute + 2116
    5   AppKit                              0x9456829e NSAccessibilityEntryPointValueForAttribute + 24
    6   AppKit                              0x9435ff4c ValueOfAttributeWithDefault + 80
    7   AppKit                              0x94090fa2 NSAccessibilityChildren + 47
    8   AppKit                              0x94090f48 NSAccessibilityUnignoredChildrenForOnlyChild + 99
    9   AppKit                              0x94090e50 NSAccessibilityUnignoredDescendant + 42
    10  AppKit                              0x94213a51 -[NSNibAXRelationshipConnector establishConnection] + 130
    11  AppKit                              0x9453e342 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1061
    12  AppKit                              0x93ffaad7 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 56
    13  AppKit                              0x945debdd -[NSNib _instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:options:] + 735
    14  AppKit                              0x941a3f77 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 277
    15  AppKit                              0x94651cee -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout) _initContentView] + 189
    16  AppKit                              0x9463d317 -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 645
    17  AppKit                              0x9463c6db +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 216
    18  AppKit                              0x945e978a +[NSOpenPanel openPanel] + 33
    19  AppKit                              0x944b66fb -[NSDocumentController _setupOpenPanel] + 42
    20  AppKit                              0x944b6b62 -[NSDocumentController beginOpenPanelWithCompletionHandler:] + 96
    21  AppKit                              0x944b6630 -[NSDocumentController openDocument:] + 413
    22  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x973bc853 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    23  AppKit                              0x94380328 __36-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 51
    24  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x9096dc03 _os_activity_initiate + 89
    25  AppKit                              0x941f3a11 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 548
    26  AppKit                              0x9420f9ed -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 479
    27  AppKit                              0x9420f6c9 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 162
    28  AppKit                              0x9420ed54 -[NSMenu _performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:sendAccessibilityNotification:] + 79
    29  AppKit                              0x94585872 __38-[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:]_block_invoke + 52
    30  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x9096dc03 _os_activity_initiate + 89
    31  AppKit                              0x94260736 -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 141
    32  AppKit                              0x9426069e -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 45
    33  AppKit                              0x94260669 -[NSMenuItem _internalPerformActionThroughMenuIfPossible] + 106
    34  AppKit                              0x942604c1 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 120
    35  AppKit                              0x94204487 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 679
    36  HIToolbox                           0x905a45d4 _Z22_InvokeEventHandlerUPPP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPvPFlS0_S2_S3_E + 36
    37  HIToolbox                           0x903ee501 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 2291
    38  HIToolbox                           0x903ed4dc _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 402
    39  HIToolbox                           0x90400d25 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
    40  HIToolbox                           0x905a4452 _ZL18SendHICommandEventmPK9HICommandmmhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 447
    41  HIToolbox                           0x904650cc SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 72
    42  HIToolbox                           0x90465074 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 207
    43  HIToolbox                           0x90464f38 _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 145
    44  HIToolbox                           0x905fb902 _ZL14MenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdmPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 775
    45  HIToolbox                           0x9046c266 _HandleMenuSelection2 + 512
    46  HIToolbox                           0x9046c050 _HandleMenuSelection + 55
    47  AppKit                              0x94182f3b _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 359
    48  AppKit                              0x9400e321 _DPSNextEvent + 1702
    49  AppKit                              0x9400d7a1 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 186
    50  AppKit                              0x93ffff6c -[NSApplication run] + 907
    51  AppKit                              0x93fe94d0 NSApplicationMain + 2082
    52  MyApp                               0x00003215 start + 53
```

Comment: if you think it's a bug, should it be reported to apple via http://bugreporter.apple.com ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the extension class you are using. `NSArray+CocoaDevUsersAdditions` `firstObject` method is implemented wrong. The relevant parts of the crash log you posted are these three lines:

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x973bea2a objc_exception_throw + 276
2   CoreFoundation                      0x97b1cf8c -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 204
3   MyApp                               0x0013c830 -[NSArray(CocoaDevUsersAdditions) firstObject] + 41
```

The `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array` error happens when you try to access the index 0 of an array that contains no objects. 
I found some code that I think matches the `NSArray+CocoaDevUsersAdditions` class at [this URL](https://github.com/tdmartin102/ajrdatabase/blob/master/EOControl/Support/NSArray%2BCocoaDevUsersAdditions.m)

```
-(id)firstObject
{
    return [self objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The above code is wrong. It should check the count of objects first. Correct code should look like this:

```
-(id)firstObject
{
    id result = nil;
    if (self.count > 0) {
        result = [self objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

So the problem is the `NSArray` extension you are using is implemented wrong.

Best solution: Remove your `NSArray+CocoaDevUsersAdditions` category and use the public `firstObject` method on `NSArray`

Comment: Just add "else return nil" or you will be in trouble (if it compiles at all).

Comment: [-\[NSArray firstObject\]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject) is actually now a public Foundation method, which is why it's being accessed from AppKit code.  It should not be overriden by a category.  Just delete the method from the category.

Comment: @Darren agreed, and having a conflicting method name in a category is not a good thing. I've updated my answer.